I'm trying to understand the swiftUI Charts API specifically overlaying charts and modifying certain aspects of the chart
I just started working with Charts in swiftui and I'm struggling. I'd like to overlay my bar chart in the image below with a line chart. But the only way I can figure out how is to embed in a ZStack, but as shown in the screenshot the two charts(same data passed for now) don't align. I'd like to show maybe an average line overlaying the bars, but I just can't figure it out. I don't know much about charting and I'm new to this API as well. Also I'd like to display the actual amount on the bar or above the bar or something. Not sure if any of this is possible in swiftui yet. If nothing else can you point me to some good documentation or additional info on Charts? Thanks

Here's a simplification of my code
        ZStack {
        Chart {
            ForEach(payments, id: \.date) { payment in

                BarMark(
                    x: .value("Date", payment.date),
                    y: .value("Amount", payment.amount)
                )
            }
        }

        Chart {

            ForEach(payments, id: \.date) { payment in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("Date", payment.date),
                    y: .value("Amount", payment.amount)
                )
            }
        }
    }


Try this approach where
you use one Chart with two ForEach, such as:
 Chart {
     ForEach(payments, id: \.date) { payment in
         BarMark(
             x: .value("Date", payment.date, unit: .day), // <-- adjust as required
             y: .value("Amount", payment.amount)
         )
     }

     ForEach(payments, id: \.0) { payment in
         LineMark(
             x: .value("Date", payment.date, unit: .day), // <-- adjust as required
             y: .value("Amount", payment.amount)
         )
     }
 }

Here is my full test code that shows how to have the BarMark together
with the LineMark on top.
struct ChartData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let value: Double
    let date: Date
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let chartData: [ChartData] = (0..<10).map { index in
        ChartData(value: Double.random(in: 1...10) ,
                  date: Date().addingTimeInterval(Double(index) * 60 * 60 * 24) )
    }

    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(chartData) { data in
                BarMark(
                    x: .value("Date", data.date, unit: .day),
                    y: .value("Value", data.value)
                )
                .foregroundStyle(Color.blue)
            }
            ForEach(chartData) { data in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("Date", data.date, unit: .day),
                    y: .value("Value", data.value)
                )
                .foregroundStyle(Color.red)
            }
        }
        .chartLegend(.hidden)
        .chartXAxis(.hidden)
        .chartYAxis(.hidden)
    }
}


no luck on that @workingdog it appends the same data to the right of the bar chart as a line chart. I'm wanting to overlay the bars with a line

it shows up as two dates if you remove all the hidden

Whaaa ok idk your code is working right as a stand alone. my eyes must be messing with me or something

ah ok yes you got it my bad I had some other logic making a string from the date and then back to ..long story short the dates don't match because I was limiting the line chart to one point a day and losing the hours etc. Thank you this has been eating at me.
